# RDD generation via (1 to N) with map fails

Tags: apache-spark

This works:

```
val rdd = sc.makeRDD((1 to 10))
val rdd2 = rdd.map(x => (1, 1,"2019-01-01", "2019-01-01",1,2,"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"))
```

This does not:

```
val rdd = sc.makeRDD((1 to 10)).map((1, 1,"2019-01-01", "2019-01-01",1,2,"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"))
```

Error gotten is:

```
notebook:1: error: type mismatch;
  found   : (Int, Int, String, String, Int, Int, String)
  required: Int => ?
```

This again does work, that's fine:

```
val rdd = sc.makeRDD((1 to  10)).map((_, 1,"2019-01-01", "2019-01-01",1,2,"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"))
```

I'm missing some finer point here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The missing point is that you have to pass a function and `(Int, Int, String, String, Int, Int, String)` is not a one.

If you want to generate constant

```
sc.makeRDD((1 to 10)).map(_ => (1, 1,"2019-01-01", "2019-01-01",1,2,"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"))
```

Comment: But why is that? Because of makeRDD? lit?

Comment: At least x => is required else _

Comment: Syntactic sugar I suspect.